# Streaming Large ISO files ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, streaming, multipartform-data

I'm trying to stream large iso files(~4Gb).
Therefore, I followed this article https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/03/12/uploading-files-asp-net-core/ (Streaming Files (Large Files) is a part I was interested in).
My Controller looks like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [DisableFormValueModelBinding]
        [Authorize]
        [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 5368709000)]
        [RequestSizeLimit(5368709000)]
        [Route("{clusterId}/image_library/upload_image")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(AsyncOperationResult), 200)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(OperationResult), 400)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), 401)]
        public IActionResult UploadFile()
        {
            bool result = Request.StreamFile("E:\\").Result; / extension method

            if (result)
            {
                return Ok();
            }

            return BadRequest();
            bool result=  Request.StreamFile("E:\\").Result; /extension method

            if (result)
            {
                return Ok();
            }

            return BadRequest();
        }
```

The DisableFormValueModelBinding Attribute implemented as follows:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
    {
        public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
        {
            var formValueProviderFactory = context.ValueProviderFactories
                .OfType<FormValueProviderFactory>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (formValueProviderFactory != null)
            {
                context.ValueProviderFactories.Remove(formValueProviderFactory);
            }

            var jqueryFormValueProviderFactory = context.ValueProviderFactories
                .OfType<JQueryFormValueProviderFactory>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (jqueryFormValueProviderFactory != null)
            {
                context.ValueProviderFactories.Remove(jqueryFormValueProviderFactory);
            }
        }

        public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
        {
        }
    }
```

And my Kestrel configured this way:

```
hostBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.AddServerHeader = false;
                    options.Listen(ipAddress, ProviderSettings.API_port);
                    options.Listen(ipAddress, ProviderSettings.API_SSL_port, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        listenOptions.UseHttps(sslSert);
                    });
                    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
                })
                .UseContentRoot(contentRootPath)
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    // Remove default Microsoft Logger
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                });
```

**The problem is that, when I post files on my controller method, they are getting loaded into RAM, but I need them to be streamed on hardrive by butches without devouring my RAM.**

Checked my middlewares: none reconfigures Kestrel settings, the same code works fine on another project(I must be missing something).
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any problem here, maybe there is a problem in your `StreamFile` extension method that process your stream.

Comment: @Mayo ,  the application throws an exception( and devour RAM), before hitting breakpoint inside the UploadFile method.

Comment: What the hell is JQueryFormValueProviderFactory? Is it possible that a some kind of 3-rd party specific framework library is supported in the controller model binding by default?